# Integrating R and its graphics with existing Javascript/HTML Application

Tags: javascript, r, node.js, rserve, opencpu

I have an existing Javascript/HTML Application. I wanted to use power of `R Programming`'s scientific computing and graphics.

My aim is to,

1. Send some data from Javascript app.
2. Call predefined R functions with the data input.
3. Get the output get the output in the form of both text and graphics.
4. Display it in the HTML page.

How to achieve this,

1. Should I run R continuously, use something like `web sockets` and connect to R? If doing How to pass R scripts to execute and get the output pack?
2. There is [Rserve](https://rforge.net/Rserve/). There are some `nodeJS` implementation for `Rserve`. But problem with this is, each line of code should be passed through the `evaluate` commands. Even though if I do so, how to handle the graph output?
3. I explored a bit of [openCPU](https://www.opencpu.org/). If using openCPU R package, R should be continuously Running with `opencpu` library and each we start R and openCPU, it starts with different port number. And if i close the R session, `opencpu` server also terminates.
4. If I install standalone `opencpu` server in my machine, how to use R with this? I've installed openCPU standalone server and a kind of stuck after that.

How should I proceed, What should I do to accomplish my task. I'm like a kind of don't know which direction to go. Please throw some light on this. I'm sure most people would need this.

I have worked with `shiny`, but in this case, I can not make use of it. Need to connect R from external Web Application.

Comment: Another option would be to export the data into a portable format (like csv) and run Rscript on an `.R` file that will find the data.

Comment: [rapier](http://trestletech.com/2015/06/rapier-convert-r-code-to-a-web-api/) might be an option for you

Comment: @RomanLuštrik: But how to get the graphics out and display in the app on the fly?

Comment: @hrbrmstr: Thanks for your suggestion. I'll explore this.

Comment: You can save the figures as files. There may be better, more elegant options, though.

Comment: Where do you get stuck with the opencpu server? You just install it on a linux box and then you can start calling functions in your R packages via the API.

Comment: @Jeroen: Thanks Jeroen. OpenCPU is great! I got stuck up because of some other dependent library. Basic test passed! Now trying to get it work with my app. Going through example apps. It solves all my problem if I get it   done. :)

Comment: @ManojG Hello sir, did you figure out how to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

[FastRWeb](https://rforge.net/FastRWeb/) sounds like it would be perfect for your needs. From the documentation:

> FastRWeb is an infrastructure that allows any webserver to use R
> scripts for generating content on the fly, such as web pages or
> graphics. URLs are mapped to scripts and can have optional arguments
> that are passed to the R function run from the script. For example
> http://my.server/cgi-bin/R/foo.png?n=100 would cause FastRWeb to look
> up a script foo.png.R, source it and call run(n="100"). So for example
> the script could be as simple as
>
> ```
> run <- function(n=10, ...) {
>    p <- WebPlot(800, 600)
>    n <- as.integer(n)
>    plot(rnorm(n), rnorm(n), col=2, pch=19)
>    p
> }
> ```

This can potentially then be called using JavaScript to dynamically load images and display them.

You might also like to think about [shiny](http://shiny.rstudio.com), though that's more of a complete solution.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try this out. I'm aware of `shiny`. I love it. I've worked with it. But in this case, I can not make use of shiny.

Answer (score 0):

You can call R from javascript efficiently using `Rserve` package. There is javascript implementation of Rserve client available [rserve-js](https://github.com/cscheid/rserve-js).
Additionally you may find it interesting the `httupv` implementation of R as a service described in this [Suggestions needed for building R server REST API's that I can call from external app?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29537593/2490497).