# Validating Inputs in R REST API

Tags: r, rest

I'm building an R REST API where I can expose some R functions/models.

I started with this question:
[Suggestions needed for building R server REST API's that I can call from external app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22179512/suggestions-needed-for-building-r-server-rest-apis-that-i-can-call-from-externa)

Added a little extra processing, and started using `httpuv`'s daemonized server function.

And it's up and working. My concern is whether or not this is safe to do. How can I be sure that I'm responding correctly to improper requests and that there's no way for a person to accidentally/maliciously inject code.

Right now, they can call the api with http://IPADDRESS:PORT/FUNCTION?a=VALUE&b=VALUE

**Is there a good way in the midst of all this text-parsing to validate my inputs?**

(It's all on our internal network, so I'm not too concerned about the malicious side, but I'd really like to know the limitations here)

Is this a "Here there be dragons" situation?

**CODE:**

```
library(httpuv)
library(RCurl)
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
```

Start with some functions:

```
#################################################################################
# API Functions
#################################################################################
APIoperations <-
  list(
    Add = function(a,b) a + b,
    Subtract = function(a,b) a - b,
    Multiply = function(a,b) a*b,
    Divide = function(a,b) a/b
  )
```

Do some validation:

```
#################################################################################
# Check if Operation is Supported
#################################################################################
validateOperation <- function(op) {
  if(op %in% names(APIoperations)) {
    op
  } else {
    # DO OTHER THINGS HERE
    # LOG, etc...
    'Unsupported'
  }
}
```

Format of an Error:

```
#################################################################################
# General Error Format
#################################################################################
returnError <- function(error = '',
                        status = 500L,
                        headers = list('Content-Type' = 'text/html'),
                        body = paste('\r\n<html><body>',error,'</body></html>')) {
  list(status = status,
       headers = headers,
       body = body)
}
```

And then my actual server Logic:

```
#################################################################################
#################################################################################
# Start Server Logic
#################################################################################
#################################################################################
app <-
  list(call =
         function(req) {
           #################################################################################
           # Grab and Parse Query
           # Only include acceptable characters

           query <- req$QUERY_STRING

           if(validateOperation(gsub('[[:punct:]]','',req$PATH_INFO)) == 'Unsupported') {
             return(list(status=501L,
                         headers=list('Content-Type' = 'text/html'),
                         body= "\r\n<html><body>Error 501<br>Unsupported Operation</body></html>"))
           }
           #################################################################################
           # Strip any punctuation in this case, other cases may need a specific parsing
           funcname <- gsub('[[:punct:]]','',req$PATH_INFO)

           #################################################################################
           # Requested Function
           reqfunc <- APIoperations[[funcname]]

           #################################################################################
           # Function Parameters
           vars <- names(formals(reqfunc))

           #################################################################################
           # Parse
           qs <- try(httr:::parse_query(gsub("^\\?", "", query)))

           #################################################################################
           # If missing vars return error
           if(!all(names(qs) %in% vars) | !all(vars %in% names(qs))) {
             errorFeed <- 'Missing Variables, or improper Code'
             returnError(errorFeed)
           }

           #################################################################################
           # Return Status 200 and type JSON
           status <- 200L
           headers <- list('Content-Type' = "application/json")


           if (!is.character(query) || identical(query, "")) {
             body <- "\r\n<html><body></body></html>"
           } else {
             body <- jsonlite::toJSON(x = list(result = do.call(reqfunc,lapply(qs,as.numeric))))
           }

           # Print Query String for testing purposes
           print(req$QUERY_STRING)


           ret <- list(status=status,
                       headers=headers,
                       body=body)

           return(ret)

         }

message("Starting server...")
```

Then I start the Server with:

```
server <- httpuv::startDaemonizedServer(<MYIPADDRESS>, <PORT>, app=app)
```

And stop it with:

```
httpuv::stopDaemonizedServer(server)
```

Comment: wow, there are packages that wrap a lot of this up for you. I've used `fastRWeb` to do this in the past and it's great.

Comment: I'll take a look through their documentation, they may have the answers there. I'm curious if there is ever an issue with R functions and special characters, I don't know that a lot of R functions were built with security in mind.